# Trying to delete multiple records at once in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm trying to make table with checkboxes where admin can check multiple products and delete them. So far I've made the form

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    {{ Form::open() }}
          <input type="checkbox" name="delete[]" value="{{ $product->product_id }}">
          <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ URL::to('/admin/products/multiDdelete') }}?_token={{ csrf_token() }}">Delete</a>
    {{ Form::close() }}
@endforeach
```

This is in my route

```
Route::get ('/admin/products/multiDdelete', ['uses' => 'AdminController@testDelete', 'before' => 'csrf|admin']);
```

And this in the controller

```
public function testDelete() {

    $delete = Input::only('delete')['delete'];

    $pDel = Product::where('product_id', $delete);

    $pDel->delete();
    return Redirect::to('/admin/test')->with('message', 'Product(s) deleted.');
}
```

So far when I check products and hit `Delete` page reload and I get **Product(s) deleted** but products aren't deleted. I think the problem is in how I pass `ID's`.. but I can't figured it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query isn't returning anything useful here. Even with `->get()`, it would return a collection, which you can't use the way you want. You can add delete to your query instead:

```
Product::whereIn('product_id', $delete)->delete();
```